# Make radio group labels display nicely inline with radio buttons using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

Previously I used a table to display radio buttons with labels. Now I am trying to do this same thing using only CSS.

[image: this was made using a table]

What can I do in CSS that will make the label text sit nicely on top of the related radio button? This is the HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cfimb_5" id="id_cfimb_5_1" value="1">
        Never
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
         <input type="radio" name="cfimb_5" id="id_cfimb_5_2" value="2">
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cfimb_5" id="id_cfimb_5_3" value="3">
        Sometimes
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cfimb_5" id="id_cfimb_5_4" value="4">
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="cfimb_5" id="id_cfimb_5_5" value="5">
        Frequently
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/keuhl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Historically, you could use margins to achieve this layout:

```css
.controls label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.controls input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1">
    Never
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2">
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="3">
    Sometimes
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="4">
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="5">
    Frequently
  </label>
</div>
```

On modern browsers that support [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), the solution is considerably easier:

```css
.controls {
  display: flex;
}

.radio {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1">
    Never
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2">
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="3">
    Sometimes
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="4">
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="5">
    Frequently
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this is solid... unfortunately twitter bootstrap CSS is in the mix and things are not displaying properly.

Comment: If you can simply link to a sample it won't be hard to override the bootstrap CSS.